# The complement of a finite set in a countable set is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a countable set. Let  $A  \subset  X$.

How can I prove that if $A$ is finite then $X  \setminus  A$ is countable?

I started off by supposing that $X  \setminus  A$ is finite and then need to show that this leads to a contradition.

The result that $X  \setminus  A$ is countable will then follow because all subsets of $X$ are countable or finite

Comment: Every subset of a countable set is countable, so I suspect that by *countable* you really mean *countably infinite*. HINT: What do you know about the union of two finite sets?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $X- A$ is finite. What does that imply about $(X-A) \cup A$?

Comment: I believe that this implies  #(X−A)∪A = #A + #(X-A) but I'm not sure what this means in the context of finding a contradiction that X-A is not finite

Comment: Let's pretend these sets are numbers. What is $(x-y)+y$?

Comment: $(x-y)+y=x$. Similarly, $(X-A)\cup A = X$. So we have expressed $X$ as the union of two finite sets. Is that kosher?

Comment: I'm still not sure where the contradiction comes in?

Comment: $X$ is infinite. Yet we've expressed $X$ as the union of two finite sets. The union of two finite sets is finite. So $X$ must be finite.

Answer (score -2):

> Let $X$ be a countable set.

Therefore, there exists an injective function $f:X\to \mathbb{N}$

By definition of injective, we have $\forall a,b\in X:[f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b] $

> Let  $A  \subset  X$.

Let $g$ be a function $g:X \setminus A \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall a\in X\setminus A: g(a)=f(a)$

1. Suppose $x,y\in X\setminus A$
2. By definition of $\setminus$, we have $x,y \in X$
3. Suppose $g(x)=g(y)$
4. By definition of $g$ ,we have $g(x)=f(x)$
5. By definition of $g$ ,we have $g(y)=f(y)$
6. $f(x)=f(y)$ (substituting 4 and 5 into 3)
7. $x=y$ (from 2 and since $f$ is injective)
8. $g(x)=g(y)\implies x=y$ (conclusion from 3 and 7)
9. $\forall a,b \in X\setminus A: [g(a)=g(b) \implies a=b]$ (conclusion from 1 and 8)
10. $g$ is an injective function $g:X\setminus A\to \mathbb{N}$ (from 9 and definition of $g$)
11. By definition, $X\setminus A$ is countable  (regardless of whether $A$ is finite)

Comment: This is a pretty complicated way of saying that a restriction of an injective function is injective.

Comment: It also seems like the OP is using the word "countable" to mean "countably infinite," in which case $A$ being finite is crucial.

Comment: @Braindead I make no assumption that $X$ is infinite. Note that the mapping $f$ need not be surjective. For example, if $X=\{ 1 \}$ then $f(1)=1$ is the required injection.

Comment: Please read the OP and my comment again. It seems that OP is using the word "countable" to mean "countably infinite." And yes, there are references that use the word "countable" to mean "countably infinite" rather than "countably infinite or finite."

Comment: @Braindead The OP does say that $A$ is finite, but it makes no difference as I pointed out on line 11. Likewise, it doesn't matter if $X$ is infinite. In any case, $X\setminus A$ would be countable if $X$ and $A$ are countable and $A\subset X$.

Comment: You are not understanding my comments. Try replacing the word "countable" in OP with "countably infinite." Also look at the comment by Brian M. Scott.

Comment: @Braindead My point is that is it doesn't matter. Either way you get the result that $X\setminus A$ is countable. But perhaps I am still not understanding. Are you saying my proof is flawed?

Comment: If you replace the word "countable" with "countably infinite" in the OP, then the problem becomes: "Let $X$ be countably infinite. How do I prove that if $A$ is finite then $X\setminus A$ is countably infinite?"

Comment: @Braindead That is quite a different problem from that given in the first two lines of the posting.

Comment: That is exactly what I have been saying this entire time. If you read the entire post (and not just the first two lines), it's pretty apparent that when OP says "countable" he really means "countably infinite."

Comment: And here, I repeat myself: There are references that use the word "countable" to mean "countably infinite" rather than "countably infinite or finite."

Comment: @Braindead I haven't previously seen any such references, but will take your word for it.

Comment: See wikipedia's entry on "Countable set."

Comment: @Braindead That's what I was using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set#Formal_definition_and_properties  But from the Princeton website I now see, "Some authors use countable set to mean a set with the same cardinality as the set of natural numbers." https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Countable_set.html

Comment: @Braindead You were right about the Wiki article. I just jumped  to the formal definition. They should have given an alternate formal definition as well -- one specifying a bijection instead of an injection.